# Javascript: obj.fn() vs x=obj.fn;x()

Tags: javascript

Take a look at this snippet:

```
var obj = {
    fn: function () {return this;}
};
var x = obj.fn;    

obj.fn();  // returns obj
x();  // returns window (in the browser)
```

I'm curious why `obj.fn()` is different from `x=obj.fn; x()`. Is there a special case for attribute lookup directly followed by a function call within a single expression - or there is some more complex magic going on under the hood (like with [descriptor protocol](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) in Python) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value from the `this` context variable always depends on how a function was invoked.

```
obj.fn();
```

will invoke the function as `method`, which means its `this` value will always reference the containing object, in this case `obj`.

By directly storing a reference in `x` the function is called "just like that" in the global scope, which means it will always reference the `global object` in non ES5-strict mode environment and it will be `undefined` in ES5 strict mode.

So, you always need to be careful when referencing object methods in variables. If such a method wants to access some data from its own object via `this.someProp`, it will obviously fail if `this` is bound to another object/context.

---

<sup>Disclaimer: "will always reference the containing object" is not entirely correct. If the function was bound to another object via `Function.prototype.bind()`, it will **always** reference that bound object.</sup>

Comment: @Tim Down: Thanks, I haven't found that myself. Unfortunately the readability of that spec is of a.. ekhm.. questionable quality :) Anyway, it's a shame that the composition of property lookup and call operator gives different results than using them separately.